# Can you convert a try/catch into a if/else in Js?

Tags: javascript, express, try-catch

Just curious if it was possible to turn a try/catch into an if/else and what the syntax would be like. Below is some of my code from an express js app I'm building for saving and deleting notes.

```
// Retrieves notes from storage
  getNotes() {
    return this.read().then((notes) => {
      let parsedNotes;
      // Below parsedNotes will add the parsed individual note to the stored notes array
      try {
        parsedNotes = [].concat(JSON.parse(notes));
      } catch (err) {
        // Returns empty array if no new note is added
        parsedNotes = [];
      }
      // Returns array
      return parsedNotes;
    });
  }
  // Adds note to array of notes
  addNote(note) {
    // Construction of note prior to save
    const { 
      title, 
      text 
    } = note;
    // Adds a ID to the new note
    const newNote = { 
      title, 
      text, 
      id: uuidv4() 
    };
    // Gets notes, adds new notes, then will update notes with new note
    return this.getNotes()
      .then((notes) => [...notes, newNote])
      .then((updatedNotes) => this.write(updatedNotes))
      .then(() => newNote);
  }
```

I'm new to programming and was just curious if it was possible and how it would be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. `if`/`else` are appropriate, for instance, if a function returns `null` or `undefined` on error. Exceptions behave differently from that: when an exception is thrown, it stops execution and jumps to the `catch` block that's associated with the closest `try` block in which the exception was thrown. If there's no `try` block at all, the program (normally) crashes. You can't check for exceptions with `if`/`else` because it will jump out of the `if` block containing it and either directly go to the `catch` block or crash the program if there is no `try` block, *without* executing any of the code inbetween.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and thorough explanation!